# Swiping Horizontal Pager looses the item state when scrolled back and forth - JetpackCompose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, jetpack-compose-accompanist

I am making a quiz app. It uses Horizontal pager, in each item there is a question and 4 option radio buttons.i have 10 items in horizontal pager.
if i reach to last page and swipe back to first the selections made are gone and the page is loaded freshly. How to save the state of the content item even when it is scrolled to last page. When using normal view pager we can set page offset which is not available in jetpack compose.How to solve this issue ?. Please help. I am using this version

```
implementation "com.google.accompanist:accompanist-pager:0.21.2-beta"
implementation "com.google.accompanist:accompanist-pager-indicators:0.21.2-beta"
```

Comment: You can store data outside of the pager, in a `mutableStateList`/`mutableStateMap` according to page index

Comment: data is stored, but in ui , the selection made in a radio button are cleared when scrolling back

Comment: You store data for each page inside `content` block, which is not reliable. If you place your data before `HorizontalPager`, it's gonna live as long as whole pager is visible

Comment: how are you saving the state of those radio buttons in UI? have you tried `rememberSaveable`